# How to get address and modify it in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

so i am making a game in mips and i printed a character, but how do i physically move that character on the screen? I want to move the character using WASD like a control pad.  This is what i have currently

```
controls:
    switchCase:
    
    li $v0, 12 # input for controls
    syscall
    move $a0, $v0
    
    la $t6, leftArrow
    lb $t6, ($t6)
    beq $a0, $t6, moveLeft
    
    la $t6, rightArrow
    lb $t6, ($t6)
    beq $a0, $t6, moveRight
    
    la $t6, upArrow
    lb $t6, ($t6)
    beq $a0, $t6, moveUp
    
    la $t6, downArrow  
    lb $t6, ($t6)
    beq $a0, $t6, moveDown
    
moveLeft:
    
    addi $t5, $t5, -4
    
    j switchCase
    #jr $ra

moveRight:
    
    addi $t5, $t5, 4
    
    j switchCase
    #jr $ra

moveUp:
    
    addi $t5, $t5, -16
    j switchCase
    #jr $ra
    
moveDown: 
    
    addi $t5, $t5, 16
    j switchCase
    #jr $ra
```

When i compile it, it just displays whatever key was pressed but nothing happens.  The character that was printed is in $t5 but doesnt move.  When i assemble step by step it is stuck at the syscall 12 instruction.  I assume i have to get the address of t5? And I am unsure if the code for the move functions are correct. Thanks!

here is the updated code i have

```
controls:

li $t8, 8
li $s5, 15

switchCase:

jal rowMajor
# addy in s5
input:
li $v0, 12 # input for controls
syscall
move $a0, $v0

la $t6, leftArrow
lb $t6, ($t6)
beq $a0, $t6, moveLeft

la $t6, rightArrow
lb $t6, ($t6)
beq $a0, $t6, moveRight

la $t6, upArrow
lb $t6, ($t6)
beq $a0, $t6, moveUp

la $t6, downArrow  
lb $t6, ($t6)
beq $a0, $t6, moveDown

moveLeft:
 

addi $s5, $s5, -4



j input
#jr $ra

moveRight:

addi $s5, $s5, 4

j input
#jr $ra

moveUp:

addi $s5, $s5, -16
j input
#jr $ra

moveDown: 

addi $s5, $s5, 16
j input
#jr $ra
```

[image: photo of text box]

Comment: FYI, registers don't have addresses.

Comment: Sorry, address of the character in the array. How would i modify and reprint that? I used row major to get address of it but not sure how to move it

Comment: You're pretty close, but just missing one thing. All your code is doing is adjusting a pointer. Which it *does* need to do, but it also needs to store something, namely, the player character tile, into screen memory. Also, you need to erase the old character from where it was. I don't know exactly how your system's video memory works (I'm assuming that it's a text screen and you're moving the player around by printing some letter). Could you provide a picture of the screen so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @puppydrum64 just uploaded a pic. Essentially, i want to move that character around, and that letter 'd' at the bottom is where the user input is

Comment: @dominic99 I think I see now what's going on here. So how do you actually display the character? If I wanted to display a zero at the position pointed to by `$s5` could I do `li $t0,0x30` followed by `sb $t0,($s5)`?

Comment: @puppydrum64 further up in the program i have a loop to display the character at the 8th row and 15th column and it just does a print instruction with load immediate and a move and then syscall print character (11)

Comment: So you're storing the entire gamefield as a string and printing it?

Comment: @puppydrum64 the same loop that prints the character also prints the outside vertical lines and if its not printing a line it will print a space. i also have a 2d array with the same area as what is printed. but yes, they are all strings in the .data section

Comment: Then you need to track where the player is, and when you move the player, print a space where the player used to be and then print the player in the new position

Comment: By tracking it, i would store the address of that point in the array correct? The problem i am having is trying to print at a specified address. When i print, it is printing next to the user input at the very bottom

Comment: Which simulator are you using? I'll try downloading it and see if I can come up with something that works